# Запятая перед «и». Согласование местоимения

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, согласование, и

Предложение вот такое ([А. Князева. Девушка из тихого омута](http://loveread.ec/read_book.php?id=78624&p=43)).

> Добравшись до Боткинской больницы, припарковалась и пошла вдоль дома тринадцать, помпезной сталинской постройки, **на котором** висели две памятные доски(,) **и** обе — писателям.

Подскажите, нужна ли запятая перед «и»? (Я бы поставила — чисто интуитивно, — но правила подобрать не могу.)
Верно ли согласовано местоимение "на котором"?

Comment: А что такое _помпезной сталинской постройки_? Пояснение? Хочется тире выделить эту конструкцию.

Answer (score 1):

*Добравшись до Боткинской больницы, припарковалась и пошла вдоль дома тринадцать, помпезной сталинской **постройки, на котором** висели две памятные доски, и обе — писателям.*

Я полагаю, что здесь есть стилистическая неточность, так как расположенные рядом слова "постройки, на котором" не сочетаются между собой, а это хорошо определяется на слух. Сочетание "постройки, на которой" тоже нежелательно, но уже по смыслу, так как речь идет о доме. Поэтому надо редактировать предложение, например:

(1) *Добравшись до Боткинской больницы, припарковалась и пошла вдоль дома тринадцать, помпезной сталинской постройки, **где** висели две памятные доски, и обе — писателям.*

**Запятая** ставится перед присоединительным союзом И в значении "причем".

(2) *Добравшись до Боткинской больницы, припарковалась и пошла вдоль дома тринадцать — помпезной сталинской постройки, **где** висели две памятные доски, причем обе  писателям.*

Обособление распространенного приложения в конце предложения с помощью тире.

Comment: Спасибо, Sharon, за подробное "разбирательство". Но — по поводу последнего предложения. Если мы с помощью тире отделяем приложение, то, думаю, вполне возможно и местоимение уже согласовать "постройкой": _...пошла вдоль дома тринадцать — помпезной сталинской **постройки, на которой** висели две памятные доски..._ Нет?

Comment: Римма, я думаю что тире на наше восприятие всего предложения не повлияет. У нас один и тот же предмет имеет три названия: дом, постройка, который/которая. В нашем сознании это именно дом (м.р.), а не постройка (ж.р.), поэтому нежелательно  использовать форму женского рода "которая".

Answer (score 0):

Это сложносочинённое предложение из трёх частей с сочинительными союзами «и».

В первой его части грамматическая основа — «[она/я] припарковалась» (нет подлежащего); во второй — «[я/она] пошла» (нет подлежащего), а в третьей — «обе» (нет сказуемого). При этом первые две части имеют общий оборот «Добравшись до Боткинской больницы», по этому перед первым «и» запятой нет.

> Добравшись до Боткинской больницы, припарковалась

и

> Добравшись до Боткинской больницы, пошла вдоль дома

А вот вторая и третья части не имеют общей придаточной части, не являются вопросительными, не являются односоставными назывными предложениями. То есть это чистый, без исключений случай сложносочинённого предложения. Запятая требуется.

> Добравшись до Боткинской больницы, припарковалась и пошла **вдоль дома** тринадцать, помпезной сталинской постройки, **на котором** висели две памятные доски, и обе — писателям.

«На котором» верно согласовано с «домом».

> Пошла вдоль дома на котором…

Comment: Приветствую Вас на сайте. Хорошо, с основой в первой части понятно. А ЧТО же тогда такое "висели  две доски"? И вы дважды забыли запятую перед "на котором". P. S. В вопросе нет ничего про первый союз "и".

Comment: Да не всё тут понятно и с первой частью. :(  Написал, исправил, задумался, и пошёл учить матчасть…

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что ответ здесь прост: мы ставим запятую перед последним "и", потому что союз "и"  имеет присоединительное значение "и притом", да и вся последняя часть - присоединительный оборот, выделяемый запятой.

Comment: Верно ли согласовано местоимение "на котором"?

Answer (score 0):

> Верно ли согласовано местоимение "на котором"?

Ну да, **на доме**. Вообще-то доски вешают на **стене** дома, но коли уж автор выбрал вариант "на доме", то и согласовывать надо с ним.

> Подскажите, нужна ли запятая перед «и»? (Я бы поставила — чисто
> интуитивно, — но правила подобрать не могу.)

Два самостоятельных предложения, с двумя основами, которые никак нельзя подогнать под правило об общем слове. Просто потому, что эти предложения изначально неоднородны.